# src="some.js?var=val" what does it actually mean?

Tags: html

After looking at some HTML sourses, I found some "meaningless" file inclusion, for both css and js.

I call this "meaningless" because,

1. `<script src="some_file.js?123"></script>` ALWAYS TOTALY EQUALS (size in bytes) TO

   `<link href="some.css?var=val" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` === the same as aforementioned.

   As we know, usually client-side technology can't parse vars which are coming from HTTP (mean from POST and GET), this job for server-side one.

So the question is, 
Why people use this? Wnen to/not to use this?

Thanks.

Comment: It could be a PHP/Python/Ruby script actually serving the .js and .css.  .js and .css does not necessarily mean that they're static files.

Comment: It can also be used as a cache breaker to force reloading of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query part might be used to prevent caching as WojtekT suggests (whether that’s successful or useful is a different issue), but it can also be used to pass data to the process that generates or serves the resource. For example, `some.css?var=rel` may cause a different version of a style sheet, or completely different style sheet, to be generated than `some.css`. The parameter could be used e.g. to pass user options (perhaps clumsier than cookies or HTML storage, but still possible).

Your assumption 3 is wrong in two ways. First, common client-side technology (client-side JavaScript) can easily process GET variables. Second, this isn’t about client-side. The reference `some.css?var=val` is processed by the browser to construct an absolute URL, keeping the query part, and then to generate a GET request to the server (passing the query part along), unless it finds out that the resource is in the browser’s cache.

Answer (score 6):

This is usually done to prevent the browser from caching static files.